# JDBI ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jdbi

Hey I'm having an issue with altering table partitions using JDBI. Here is an example of the query I'm trying to run:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PARTITION P_1
```

This runs fine in MySQL when dropping the partition "P_1" from the table "table1."

I've implemented it in my java code as the following:

```
@SqlUpdate("ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PARTITION :partition;")
public void deletePartition(@Bind("partition") String partition);
```

And call this function as such

```
deletePartition("P_1")
```

However, this results in the following error:

> Causing: org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''P_1'' at line 1 [statement:"ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PARTITION :partition;", located:"ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PARTITION :partition;", rewritten:"/* HiveDropBoxDBI.deletePartition */ ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PARTITION ?;", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{partition:'P_1'}, finder:[]}]

Is this functionality not supported? Or am I missing something with my syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for editing out the spoiler! Didn't realize that's what the "+" symbol did, as it was part of the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use @Define for changing the query. @Bind is only for used for binding parameters (like some_field = :value).

```
  @SqlUpdate("ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PARTITION :partition;")
  public void deletePartition(@Bind("partition") String partition);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bind parameters for DDL such as `CREATE`, `ALTER` and `DROP`.

In order to drop your partition, you must concatenate the partition name onto the query instead.

However, taking a partition name and appending it straight into a SQL string which gets executed is a recipe for a security vulnerability.  Consider some of the following:

- 'escaping' the partition name with backticks,
- checking that the partition name contains only certain whitelisted characters (e.g. alphanumerics and underscores),
- querying the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitions-table.html) table to see if the partition you're trying to drop exists.  (This might not be a good idea if there is a chance that the partition may be created or dropped between checking for its existence and dropping it.  I don't know your application well enough to say whether this would be a problem.)

As JDBI relies on constant strings for `@SqlUpdate` annotations, you will not be able to use JDBI in this way to drop partitions, unless you only ever want to drop the same partition.